# How do you get input to assign the values of structs from user input while in another struct's impl?

Tags: string, input, rust, self

I am making a number guessing game, where the player who guesses the closest wins.

```
struct Player {
    name: String,
    balance: i32,
    betamount: i32,
    guess: i32
}

struct Game {
    p1: Player,
    p2: Player,
    random_card: i32
}

impl Game {
    pub fn start(&mut self) {
        //start function
    }
}
```

How I can assign the `name` attribute of `p1` and `p2` inside the `start` function? Is this allowed?

Comment: Did you try it? What happened when you tried? [(Yes, it's allowed.)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f6fdfa5d36038cb55e13b9cb55ca79b0)

Answer (score 0):

Use the interior mutability pattern.

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct Player {
name: RefCell<String>,
balance: i32,
betamount: i32,
guess: i32
}

struct Game {
    p1: Player,
    p2: Player,
    random_card: i32
}

impl Game {
    pub fn start(&mut self) {
        //start function
       
        self.p1.name.replace_with(|_|"c".to_string());
        self.p2.name.replace_with(|_|"c".to_string());
        println!("{}",self.p1.name.borrow_mut())
    }
}

fn main() {
  let mut game = Game{
      p1: Player {
          name: RefCell::new("a".to_string()),
          balance: 0,
          betamount: 0,
          guess: 0
      },
      p2: Player {
          name: RefCell::new("b".to_string()),
          balance: 0,
          betamount: 0,
          guess: 0
      },
      random_card: 0
  };
    game.start();
}
```

Player objects are immutable, but if we want to mutate their fields, we can wrap them (the fields) in RefCell or Cell.